# Javascript : code not working as it should

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was asked in school to code in JS a ball that bounces on the edges of the html canvas it is in. I wanted to go deeper and put four balls in that canvas, and add some "physics" in the JS in order to have the balls bounce when they encounter.

I can give you more details if you want.
PS : I'm french, so it might impact the understanding of the code (since the var names are in french for the teachers)

Here's the whole code :

```
window.onload = function()
{
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mon_canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    var rafraichissement = setInterval(animation, 1000/60);

    var rBalle = parseFloat(prompt('Entrez le rayon des balles'));

    var vitesseX = 1.1;
    var vitesseY = 1.2;

    var vitesseX2 = -1.5;
    var vitesseY2 = -0.9;

    var vitesseX3 = -1.2;
    var vitesseY3 = 1.33;

    var vitesseX4 = 2;
    var vitesseY4 = -0.7;

    var xBalle = rBalle+1;
    var yBalle = rBalle+1;

    var xBalle2 = canvas.width - rBalle -1;
    var yBalle2 = canvas.height - rBalle -1;

    var xBalle3 = canvas.width - rBalle -1;
    var yBalle3 = rBalle +1;

    var xBalle4 = rBalle +1;
    var yBalle4 = canvas.height - rBalle -1;
    //canvas.width pour la largeur du canvas
    //canvas.height pour sa hauteur

    function animation() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle, yBalle, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle2, yBalle2, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle3, yBalle3, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath()

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle4, yBalle4, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath()

        //collision balles / bord du canvas

        if(xBalle >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle <= rBalle){vitesseX *= -1;}            //Balle 1 (haut gauche)
        if(yBalle >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle <= rBalle){vitesseY *= -1;}

        if(xBalle2 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle2 <= rBalle){vitesseX2 *= -1;}         //Balle 2 (bas droite)
        if(yBalle2 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle2 <= rBalle){vitesseY2 *= -1;}

        if(xBalle3 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle3 <= rBalle){vitesseX3 *= -1;}         //Balle 3 (haut droite)
        if(yBalle3 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle3 <= rBalle){vitesseY3 *= -1;}

        if(xBalle4 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle4 <= rBalle){vitesseX4 *= -1;}         //Balle 4 (bas gauche)
        if(yBalle4 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle4 <= rBalle){vitesseY4 *= -1;}


        //collision balles / balles
        //var distance entre les balles

        var dist12 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle2)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle2)), 2)));
        var dist13 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle3)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle3)), 2)));
        var dist14 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        var dist23 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle2) + parseFloat(xBalle3)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle2) + parseFloat(yBalle3)), 2)));
        var dist24 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle2) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle2) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        var dist34 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle3) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle3) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        //boucles if vérifiant la valeur de la distance, ainsi que les directions des balles

        if(dist12 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 2
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX2 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY2 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY2 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist13 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 3
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX3 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist14 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 4

            if(vitesseX*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist23 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 3
            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist24 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 4

            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist34 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 3 et 4
            if(vitesseX3*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX3 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX3 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY3*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY3 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY3 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        //Pour déplacer les balles dans le plan

        xBalle += vitesseX;
        yBalle += vitesseY;

        xBalle2 += vitesseX2;
        yBalle2 += vitesseY2;

        xBalle3 += vitesseX3;
        yBalle3 += vitesseY3;

        xBalle4 += vitesseX4;
        yBalle4 += vitesseY4;
    }
}
```

The part that does not work as it should is this one :

```
//collision balles / balles
        //var distance entre les balles

        var dist12 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle2)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle2)), 2)));
        var dist13 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle3)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle3)), 2)));
        var dist14 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        var dist23 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle2) + parseFloat(xBalle3)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle2) + parseFloat(yBalle3)), 2)));
        var dist24 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle2) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle2) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        var dist34 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((parseFloat(xBalle3) + parseFloat(xBalle4)), 2) + Math.pow(Math.pow((parseFloat(yBalle3) + parseFloat(yBalle4)), 2)));

        //boucles if vérifiant la valeur de la distance, ainsi que les directions des balles

        if(dist12 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 2
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX2 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY2 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY2 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist13 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 3
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX3 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist14 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 4

            if(vitesseX*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist23 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 3
            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist24 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 4

            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist34 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 3 et 4
            if(vitesseX3*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX3 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX3 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY3*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY3 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY3 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }
```

Tell me if you need anything more.

Comment: Please post a complete, executable example and a specific description of the problem, not just "code is not working". Can you edit the question to include the html? There is no need to post the broken js twice, just add a comment in the entire code that says it isn't working. Explain what it is doing and what it should do instead. Bonne chance!

Comment: Using an array of objects would be way better than having balle1, balle2 etc. It's also a good habit to name all functions and variables in English. That helps a lot if you're working on an open source project or in a company with people from other countries.

Answer (score 0):

The values (`dist12`, `dist13`, `dist14`, `dist23`, `dist24`, `dist34`) for the distances between each ball that you were calculating were returning `NaN`, indicating that the value was not a number.

I've fixed these calculations for you using the approach described in the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection#Circle_Collision). The rest of your collision detection code will now work as expected.

```js
 window.onload = function()
{
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('mon_canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    var rafraichissement = setInterval(animation, 1000/60);

    var rBalle = parseFloat(prompt('Entrez le rayon des balles'));

    var vitesseX = 1.1;
    var vitesseY = 1.2;

    var vitesseX2 = -1.5;
    var vitesseY2 = -0.9;

    var vitesseX3 = -1.2;
    var vitesseY3 = 1.33;

    var vitesseX4 = 2;
    var vitesseY4 = -0.7;

    var xBalle = rBalle+1;
    var yBalle = rBalle+1;

    var xBalle2 = canvas.width - rBalle -1;
    var yBalle2 = canvas.height - rBalle -1;

    var xBalle3 = canvas.width - rBalle -1;
    var yBalle3 = rBalle +1;

    var xBalle4 = rBalle +1;
    var yBalle4 = canvas.height - rBalle -1;
    //canvas.width pour la largeur du canvas
    //canvas.height pour sa hauteur

    function animation() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle, yBalle, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle2, yBalle2, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath();

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle3, yBalle3, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath()

        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(xBalle4, yBalle4, rBalle, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
        context.closePath()

        //collision balles / bord du canvas

        if(xBalle >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle <= rBalle){vitesseX *= -1;}            //Balle 1 (haut gauche)
        if(yBalle >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle <= rBalle){vitesseY *= -1;}

        if(xBalle2 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle2 <= rBalle){vitesseX2 *= -1;}         //Balle 2 (bas droite)
        if(yBalle2 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle2 <= rBalle){vitesseY2 *= -1;}

        if(xBalle3 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle3 <= rBalle){vitesseX3 *= -1;}         //Balle 3 (haut droite)
        if(yBalle3 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle3 <= rBalle){vitesseY3 *= -1;}

        if(xBalle4 >= canvas.width - rBalle || xBalle4 <= rBalle){vitesseX4 *= -1;}         //Balle 4 (bas gauche)
        if(yBalle4 >= canvas.height - rBalle || yBalle4 <= rBalle){vitesseY4 *= -1;}

        //collision balles / balles
        //var distance entre les balles

        var dist12 = Math.sqrt((xBalle - xBalle2) * (xBalle - xBalle2) + (yBalle - yBalle2) * (yBalle - yBalle2));
        var dist13 = Math.sqrt((xBalle - xBalle3) * (xBalle - xBalle3) + (yBalle - yBalle3) * (yBalle - yBalle3));
        var dist14 = Math.sqrt((xBalle - xBalle4) * (xBalle - xBalle4) + (yBalle - yBalle4) * (yBalle - yBalle4));
  var dist23 = Math.sqrt((xBalle2 - xBalle3) * (xBalle2 - xBalle3) + (yBalle2 - yBalle3) * (yBalle2 - yBalle3));
  var dist24 = Math.sqrt((xBalle2 - xBalle4) * (xBalle2 - xBalle4) + (yBalle2 - yBalle4) * (yBalle2 - yBalle4));
        var dist34 = Math.sqrt((xBalle3 - xBalle4) * (xBalle3 - xBalle4) + (yBalle3 - yBalle4) * (yBalle3 - yBalle4));
        

        ////boucles if vérifiant la valeur de la distance, ainsi que les directions des balles
        if(dist12 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 2
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX2 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY2 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY2 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY2 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist13 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 3
            if(vitesseX*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX3 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist14 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 1 et 4

            if(vitesseX*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist23 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 3
            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX3 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX2 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY3 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY3 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY3 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist24 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 2 et 4

            if(vitesseX2*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX2 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX2 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY2*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY2 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY2 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        if(dist34 <= parseFloat(rBalle)*2){  //balles 3 et 4
            if(vitesseX3*vitesseX4 < 0)
            {
                vitesseX3 *= -1; vitesseX4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseX3 *= 1; vitesseX4 *= 1;
            }

            if(vitesseY3*vitesseY4 < 0){
                vitesseY3 *= -1; vitesseY4 *= -1;
            }
            else{
                vitesseY3 *= 1; vitesseY4 *= 1;
            }
        }

        //Pour déplacer les balles dans le plan

        xBalle += vitesseX;
        yBalle += vitesseY;

        xBalle2 += vitesseX2;
        yBalle2 += vitesseY2;

        xBalle3 += vitesseX3;
        yBalle3 += vitesseY3;

        xBalle4 += vitesseX4;
        yBalle4 += vitesseY4;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mon_canvas"></canvas>
```